# Dependency problems when creating virtual environment

Tags: apt, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

I am working on an Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8 installed. I'm following a tutorial to get YOLOv5 working (https://medium.com/quantrium-tech/working-with-yolov5-7623a41fbdf8) for a research project. The tutorial recommends setting up a virtual environment to run YOLOv5 in. However when I try to install a python virtual environment with:

`$ sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv`

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcuinj64-10.1 : Depends: libcuda1 (>= 418.39) or
                            libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                            libcuda.so.1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                            libcuda-10.1-1
 libnvidia-ml-dev : Depends: libnvidia-ml1 (>= 418.39) or
                             libnvidia-tesla-440-ml1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                             libnvidia-tesla-418-ml1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                             libnvidia-ml.so.1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4) but 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I tried the recommended:

```
$ apt --fix-broken install
```

I got the following error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

People recommended using aptitude instead of apt and when I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

I got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.12-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libcuinj64-10.1 : Depends: libcuda1 (>= 418.39) or
                            libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                            libcuda.so.1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                            libcuda-10.1-1
 libnvidia-ml-dev : Depends: libnvidia-ml1 (>= 418.39) or
                             libnvidia-tesla-440-ml1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                             libnvidia-tesla-418-ml1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                             libnvidia-ml.so.1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Basically, I can't even install aptitude because of the same dependency problems that are hindering my virtual environment. I also ran:

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update
```

and tried to directly install the missing packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcuinj64-10.1
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-ml-dev
```

I tried purging cuda and nvidia with:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*" "nsight*" 
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
```

when this didn't work I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*
```

so far absolutely nothing on StackExchange or StackOverflow has worked and I am getting desperate to get this working. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: the problem with your `apt --fix-broken install` is that you need `sudo` for that. It even says so in the error: "are you root?" no, you aren't, because you didn't use `sudo`, and that's the issue. try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and see if that helps.

Comment: The version of your Python3.8 package `3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1` is from some non-Ubuntu source. That's bad. Undo whatever you did and restore the Ubuntu-provided version of Python 3.8 that came with 20.04. It will make your system less likely to fail, and will incidentally cure one of your listed version conflicts.